# Android: getLayoutInflater() problem

Tags: android, layout, layout-inflater

I have the following lines in my code:

```
View convertView;
convertView = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.classheader, parent, false);
```

And I have a "classheader.xml" in the layout folder.

However; I get this error: "classheader cannot be resolved or is not a field".

Can anybody please help me to find out what is the reason for this error?

Thanks

Comment: Try cleaning and rebuilding the project.

Comment: no problem with your code it seems just save all the files including xml files again clean it and run it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you including com.android.R by mistake in your import declaration.

Comment: Thanks, that was the problem. I removed the "import android.R" and it worked. Thanks for the help.